# Sharepoint calendar add new item correct date

Tags: 2013, calendar

I've got a calendar in SP2013. When I navigate to a specific day in month view and click the +Add on that day I would expect the default day value filled in for start/end to be the day I clicked, not today.

For example I want to add US holidays to my calendar. I flip ahead to Valentines day February 14, 2016 and click add. Instead of 2/14/16 I get 10/29/15.

Am I missing something?

Today makes sense as the default for just clicking new item because there is no way to know what day I'm looking at.

Is there a way to make this work as expected?